# Html5 Websockets for Android

Tags: html

i want to build a html5 multiplayer casino game, but it seems Android not supporting Web sockets, please guys suggest me any alternatives.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get an overview on what devices support Web Sockets [on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/websockets). This states you're right: no websockets support on android so far. The alternative is using ajax to fetch a small JSON repetitively. Ways to do this include [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [the jsonp plugin for jQuery](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp).

Comment: hi Cristan thanks for ur reply.. just got a link saying that Socket.Io seems to work, actually its a node.js library, but now it is also available with java..